# ViewBag does not show messege in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I created 2 div's inside a view. 
to display content inside that i have used partial view and to show errors i am using Viewbag and displayed it as follows:

```
 <div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Publish Exhibition</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Edit Existing Exhibition</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1"  style=" width:900px; height:400px;">
<font color="red">@ViewBag.msg1</font>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("PubExhi", Model);}
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("EditExhi");}
</div>
</div>
```

I'm calling this view as

```
 ViewBag.msg1 = "record not updated!!!!";
   modelList = setIndex();
                                return View("Index", modelList);
```

evry thing is working fine except the viewbag
it is not displaying any msgs

When i debugged it, i can see the viewbag containing appropriate value
but it is not displaying  on the page

I also tried to display it from the partial view but not getting any message

Can any body help me

Answer (score 2):

Use `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.msg1)` to display.....

Answer (score 1):

It should work, i tried exactly similar thing and it is working for me -

```
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#HWTab">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#AdminTab">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="HWTab">
    <font color="red">@ViewBag.msg</font>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_HardwareAssetView", Model.hardwareAssetVM);}
    </div>
    <div id="AdminTab">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_AdminAssetView", Model.adminAssetVM);}
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this in my other views, there it is showing the message but not in this view

Comment: You have applied some style to that particular div ie. height and width, may be that would be blocking your message from displaying properly.Have you tried changing that values.

Comment: i chked the Viewsource file of that page but it is showing me  <font color="red"></font> instead of msg..even if the proble is bcoz style attribute, it shd atleast show that in view source file....am i rite??

Comment: Yes..you r rit..this seems strange if you are not passing an empty string to this view bag accidently..!! i've upvoted your question, also give a try to Tempdata or Viewdata instead of Viewbag.

Comment: you need to assign it to the view you are sending in your server method: let's say my viewresult is Crete, but you are sending view CreateNew, then you need to assign this view's viewbag the message you want:
var partialViewRes = new PartialViewResult();
partialViewRes.ViewName = "Details";
partialViewRes.ViewData.Model = list;
partialViewRes.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error on loading";

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign it to the view you are sending in your server method: let's say my viewresult is Details, but you are sending view DetailingList, then you need to assign this view's viewbag the message you want:

```
 var partialViewRes = new PartialViewResult();
 partialViewRes.ViewName = "DetailingList";
 partialViewRes.ViewData.Model = list;
 partialViewRes.ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Error on loading";
```

Hope this helps someone.